# Hybris CDC customize GigyaLoginAddon, GigyaFacades and GigyaServices

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, gigya

I need to customize this OOTB extensions, in order to achieve this and create my own custom logic which are the steps that I must follow? Do I have to create through ant extgen a new extension based on Gigya template (if this exists) and there override the beans or can I just override the bean in my trainingfacades extension?

Comment: just extend there facade and override the method and override bean alias with custom bean.

Comment: Where should I add the new facade? To trainingfacades? And If I want to override the controller of gigyaloginaddon?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to change a facade or service you can just extend the default implementation and override the public method you want to change. An example is the product service here:

```java
public class TrainingGigyaServiceImpl extends DefaultGigyaService implements GigyaService
{
    // Override your methods here
}
```

Then define a unique bean for it and override the only the alias with your newly created bean id:

```xml
<alias name="trainingGigyaService" alias="gigyaService"/>
```

Make also sure you load the gigya* extensions before your training extension by adding it to the `extensioninfo.xml`

This process of overriding is also more elaborated on the SAP help page https://help.sap.com/viewer/aa417173fe4a4ba5a473c93eb730a417/v2105/en-US/034a7f51580e45b19d67c51cc3e6a6dc.html